# SSRS: execute query based on user input

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I want to generate a `SSRS` report in matrix form. It will fetch a data from "student" table. the columns are as following:

```
id|name|department|course|subject1|subject2|subject3|average|
```

- I want to pass "id,name,department,course" as mandatory user inputs and "subject1,subject2,subject3,average" as optional user inputs.
- If mandatory options are only passed, the result should contain  the student's id, name and department.
- If optional user inputs are also passed, then the results should get refined according to user inputs.

As I am new to `SSRS` and `SQL server`, I don't know how to write query for above criteria. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the query according to the parameters, I would change the visibility of columns. In that case, you can work with a table instead of a matrix and your query will stay the same in all cases.
Just add parameters like *showCourse*, *showSubject1* and set the visibility accordingly.

`=Parameters!showCourse.Value`

Comment: Then please explain your requirement better. Matrix is should be used only if the number of columns isn't known before executing the query. In your case, it is known as far as I see.